# After install anaconda try to use jupyter notebook. but it shows error on command and anaconda prompt

Tags: python, python-3.x, anaconda, jupyter-notebook

After install anaconda try to use jupyter notebook. but it shows error on command and anaconda prompt

```
C:\Users\nEW u>jupyter notebook

Unable to create process using 
`'C:\Users\nEW u\Anaconda3\python.exe "C:\Users\nEW u\Anaconda3\Scripts\jupyter-script.py"` notebook'
```

Comment: which version you are using?

Comment: i am using intel i5 with 6 gb ram ,and python 3.6 64-bit and anaconda 3-5.0.1

Comment: can you check if python is installed correctly by typing **python** in your cmd?

Comment: yes it installed correctly i already check

Comment: It doesn't seem a valid path `C:\Users\nEW u\Anaconda3\python.exe` as there is a space which will separate `nEW u` into `nEW` and `u`. Maybe you need to rename...